# Kiel traduki "I demand satisfaction!" esperante?

Tags: phrase-requests

Por provoki duelon, deknaŭjarcentaj sinjoroj ekkriis anglalingve, "I demand satisfaction!"

Kiel traduki tion esperantlingve?

Ĝis nun, mia plej bona provo estas: "Mi devas restarigi mian honoron!"

Ĉu oni povas plibonigi ĝin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unu eblo estas la vorto ***[kontentigo](http://vortaro.net/#kontentigo)***, kiun PIV difinas jene:.

> Ago de iu, io kontentiganta: la *kontentigo de sia malsato; mi
>   postulas de vi kontentigon por la honto, kiu estas farita al mi;
>   postuli kontentigon pri iu afero; doni kontentigon al la sinjoro;
>   kontentiga respondo; kontentige solvi malfacilaĵon*.

Jen ekz. el Tekstaro:

> [...] kia ajn estus via teoria opinio pri la duelo, en la praktiko vi
>   ne permesus vin ofendi sen postuli kontentigon.

Sekve, laŭ la supra ekzemplo, la traduko de ***I demand satisfaction!*** estus ***Mi postulas kontentigon!***

Alia eblo estas uzi la neologismon ***[satisfakcio](http://vortaro.net/#satisfakcio)***, kies unuan signifon PIV difinas jene:

> Eblo dueli kontraŭ persono, kiu ofendis: *doni, preni satisfakcion*.

Comment: Ambaŭ "postuli kontentigon" kaj "postuli kompenson" bonas. Kvankam la plena signifo de "(honor)riparo" estas tuj klara, la duobligita "r" sonas kaj aspektas (laŭ mi) iomete malbela. Mi trovis kelkajn zamenhofajn precedencojn de "postuli kompenson" en Tekstaro, do mi uzos tiun:>al Sro de Sotenville – Sinjoro, vi vidas, kiel false mi estis akuzita: vi estas homo, kiu scias la principojn de honoro, kaj mi postulas de vi kontentigon por la honto, kiu estas farita al mi.

Answer (score 0):

Mi uzus [kompens/](http://vortaro.net/#kompenso):

```
Mi postulas kompenson (pro la honoro vundita)
```

*kompens/* aperas en la difinoj de alia eblo:

[*ripari*](http://vortaro.net/#riparo) *Rebonigi, iel kompensante*

Do vi ankaŭ povus diri:

```
Mi postulas (honor)riparon
```